# How to use TabLayoutResource and ToolbarResource in .net MAUI?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, maui, android-toolbar

I'm migrating my Xamarin forms code to .NET MAUI. I need the replacement of the Following code in .NET MAUI:

```
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

I have no clue how to fix this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a new Maui app, you will find that there are no such files(`Resource.Layout.Tabbar` and `Resource.Layout.Toolbar`).

For how to upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to a .NET MAUI app, you can check documents:

[Upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to a .NET MAUI app with the .NET Upgrade Assistant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/upgrade-assistant?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vswin)  ,

[Manually upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to a multi-project .NET MAUI app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-multi-project?view=net-maui-8.0)   and

[Manually upgrade a Xamarin.Forms app to a single project .NET MAUI app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/migration/multi-project-to-single-project?view=net-maui-8.0).

Comment: Is there any replacement of Resource.Layout.Tabbar and Resource.Layout.Toolbar in MAUI?

Comment: Maui integrates all of the features you mentioned. In Maui, you can use [NET MAUI Shell tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-8.0) to achieve the same effect as `Tabbar ` .  And  [Shell.TitleView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/pages?view=net-maui-8.0#display-views-in-the-navigation-bar) to achieve the same effect as `Toolbar`.